# Javascript if condition with substring

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input, substring, conditional-statements

I try to make some inputs to be completed according the input from the textfield `value_master`.
For instance, if I type `123` in the textfield `value_master` I want to have a specific text in every `value_slave` field, but if I type `223` I want something else.

I managed to this and is working without the if conditions. With that I get this: `slave.substring is not a function`. Is important to use substring because I will have more fileds to be completed based on specific position of master value.

```
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var master = document.getElementById('value_master');
        var slave = document.getElementById('value_slave');

        document.getElementById('value_master').onkeyup = function(){
            if (slave.substring(0,1).equals("1") )          
            {
                slave.value = 'you typed something starting with 1';
            }
            else {
                slave.value = 'you typed something starting with 2';
            }
        };
    };
```

Comment: FYI: you are triggering unnecessary semicolon autoinsertion checks if you write `{` in a new line in javascript. also if it ever auto inserts a semicolon due to a syntax issue in the line above the `{` your code might behave undesired instead of throwing a usable error message. this is not c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your code to the following:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('value_master').onkeyup = function() {
        var slave = document.getElementById('value_slave');
        if (slave.value.substring(0,1).equals("1") )          
        {
            slave.value = 'you typed something starting with 1';
        }
        else {
            slave.value = 'you typed something starting with 2';
        }
    };
};
```

`slave` is the element in your code, not the value of the element. To get the value of an element you have to use `element.value`. Also, the value is only set once, when the windows loads. But not updated. To always work with the entered value, move the `var slave = document.getElementById('value_slave');` inside the `onkeyup` function.

Comment: I had to change the if condition to this if (slave.value.substring(0,1)===("1") )  but no matter what I type it execute the else condition

Comment: Got it. This is it window.onload = function()
{
    var master = document.getElementById('value_master');

    document.getElementById('value_master').onkeyup = function() {
        var slave = document.getElementById('value_slave');
        if (master.value.substring(0,1) === ("1") )          
        {
            slave.value = 'you typed something starting with 1';
        }
        else {
            slave.value = 'you typed something starting with 2';
        }
    };
};

Comment: Than you Marvin!

Answer (score 0):

`slave` is an element not a string. Try to get the value of it.

```
document.getElementById('value_master').onkeyup = function() {
   var slave = document.getElementById('value_slave').value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have this, with no error but still not working: window.onload = function()
{
 var master = document.getElementById('value_master').value;
 var slave = document.getElementById('value_slave').value;

 document.getElementById('value_master').onkeyup = function(){
  if (master.substring(0,1) === 1 )   
  {
   slave.value = 'masculin';
  }
  else {
   slave.value = 'feminin';
  }
 };
};

Comment: need to move getting the value inside the onkeyup handler